# Why is the AJAX response empty on mobile but not on PC?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX script which fetches some data thru PHP and then outputs the response to some divs. This works perfect on PCs but not on mobile devices. The thing is that the AJAX function seems to be runned on mobile devices, but the response seems to be empty or something?

Calling the AJAX function:

```
$("body").on("click tap vclick", ".className", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ajaxTest();
});
```

AJAX function:

```
function ajaxTest(){

    .........

    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://localhost/page/file.php',
        data: {value: value},
        dataType:'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result){
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = result.name;
                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = result.age;
        }
    });
}
```

in the ajaxTest() I also have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#overlay").show();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#overlay").hide();
    });
});
```

and the overlay div dissapears after some milliseconds meaning that the AJAX response was recevied, right? Or does that only mean that the function ended...?

Another wierd thing is that if I put an alert() inside sucess, the alert never comes which would probably mean that the success is never runned.

I hope that someone can help me with this

Comment: How do you access local host via mobile?

Comment: @ab_in with IPv4 having the phone on the same wifi as the webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mobile you connect with something like 192.168.xxx.xxx and on your desktop you use localhost, right?

On your mobile the localhost location does not work, you should also change that to the IP of your pc than everything should work fine.

change

> url: 'http://localhost/page/file.php'

to

> url: 'http://192.168.xxx.xxx/page/file.php'

When testing on your pc you should also use the ip.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks alot!